# Cannot import scipy.misc.imsave or cv2.imwrite

Tags: opencv, module, scipy, python-imaging-library, importerror

I need to save images from an array, so I decided to use `scipy.misc.imsave`, I got the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'imsave' from 'scipy.misc' (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\__init__.py)
```

After using pip to reinstall scipy and Pillow with no luck, I decided to try opencv-python. However, when I `import cv2.imwrite`, I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2.imwrite'
```

I again used pip to reinstall opencv-python and Pillow with no luck. Is there an underlying library needed for both of these that I am missing? I have a feeling that the issue lies with Pillow (PIL), but I'm out of ideas in terms of troubleshooting. Any direction would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: FYI: `scipy.misc.imsave` was deprecated for a long time and was removed in SciPy 1.3.0.  If you have opencv, you would use `import cv2` and then refer to the function `cv2.imwrite` in your code.  Or you can import the function as `from cv2 import imwrite` and then refer to `imwrite` in your code.  Other options for writing images are [`imageio`](https://pypi.org/project/imageio/), a "library for reading and writing a wide range of image, video, scientific, and volumetric data formats"; or [`numpngw`](https://pypi.org/project/numpngw/), a module that I wrote for writing arrays to PNG files.

Comment: Yes, I have tried cv2. I get a similar error which is written in my question.

Comment: So you tried exactly the statement `import cv2` and you got `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'`?  That means you do not have opencv installed correctly.

Comment: Yes, that is my issue. I have tried installing and reinstalling a few times using pip. I also tried installing while running as administrator. Nothing has worked so far

Comment: did you mean `from cv2 import imwrite`?

Comment: @Masoud `from cv2 import imwrite` does the same thing as `import cv2.imwrite` and yes, I have tried both.

Answer (score 0):

You can install opencv for python using this command:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

then open new command promt and type

```
python
```

then test installation of OPENCV using :

```
import cv2
```

please report your output. and tell me, which OS and environment for python you are using.